# running specflow scenario multiple times in parallel

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I have a situation where I am trying to execute the same specflow scenario multiple times in parallel, but when I run this it results in one of a number of errors (intermittent suggesting a race condition)

the errors are

```
BoDi.ObjectContainerException:Object container disposed

at BoDi.ObjectContainer.AssertNotDisposed()
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, String name)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.BindingInstanceResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer scenarioContainer)
at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 )
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
at LoadFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
at LoadFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
at LoadFeature.AddTwoNumbersTogether(String number1, String number2, String answer, String runNumber, String[] exampleTags) in ...
```

and

```
System.Argument Exception: An item with the same key has already been added

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, String name)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.BindingInstanceResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer scenarioContainer)
at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 )
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
at LoadFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
```

the code that produces this is:

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers together
    Given numbers <number1> and <number2> for run <runNumber>
    When I add them together for run <runNumber>
    Then I get <answer> for run <runNumber>
    Scenarios:
        | number1 | number2 | answer | runNumber |
        | 1       | 2       | 3      | 1         |
        | 2       | 2       | 4      | 2         |

Scenario Outline: Load test addy ups parallel
    When I execute scenario 'Add two numbers together' in parallel <load> times with parameters <parameters>
    Then All is well
    Scenarios:
        |  load | service  |parameters | 
        |  5    | 'devenv' |'1,2,3,x'  |

 [Binding]
public class LoadSteps
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<long, RunData> runParameters;
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<long, int> _results;

    static LoadSteps()
    {
        runParameters = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, RunData>();
        _results = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, int>();
    }

    [Given(@"numbers (.*) and (.*) for run (.*)")]
    public void GivenNumbersAnd(int p0, int p1, int runNumber)
    {
        runParameters.AddOrUpdate(runNumber, new RunData { Number1 = p0, Number2 = p1 }, (key, value) => new RunData { Number1 = p0, Number2 = p1 });
    }

    [When(@"I add them together for run (.*)")]
    public void WhenIAddThemTogether(int runNumber)
    {
        if (!runParameters.ContainsKey(runNumber))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"runParameters do not contain the required key {runNumber}, only contains {string.Join(",", runParameters.Keys)}");
        }
        else
        {
            var result = runParameters[runNumber].Number1 + runParameters[runNumber].Number2;
            _results.AddOrUpdate(runNumber, result, (k,v) => result);
        }
    }

    [When(@"I execute scenario '(.*)' in parallel (.*) times with parameters '(.*)'")]
    public void WhenIExecuteScenarioInParallelTimes(string p0, int p1, string p2)
    {
        var parameters = p2.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Cast<object>().Concat(new object[] { (string[])null }).ToArray();
        var feature = new LoadFeature();
        var po = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = p1 };
            Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, p1), x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                var scenario = FindScenario<TelephonyLoadFeature>(p0);

                var parameters1 = new object[parameters.Length];
                Array.Copy(parameters, parameters1, parameters.Length);
                parameters1[parameters.Length - 2] = x.ToString();

                scenario.Invoke(feature, parameters1);

                Console.WriteLine($"{x} finished");
            });
    }

    [Then(@"I get (.*) for run (.*)")]
    public void ThenIGet(int p0, int runNumber)
    {
        if (!_results.ContainsKey(runNumber))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"results do not contain the required key {runNumber}, only contains {string.Join(",", _results.Keys)}");
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(p0, _results[runNumber]);
        }
    }

    [Then(@"All is well")]
    public void ThenAllIsWell()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    private static MethodInfo FindScenario<T>(string p0)
        where T : new()
    {
        var scenario = typeof(T).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Name.Equals(p0.Replace(" ", string.Empty), System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (scenario == null)
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        return scenario;
    }

    private struct RunData
    {
        public int Number1 { get; set; }

        public int Number2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

note that running the base scenario multiple times sequentially works fine

```
Scenario Outline: Load test addy ups sequential
    When I execute scenario 'Add two numbers together' in sequence <load> times with parameters <parameters>
    Then All is well
    Scenarios:
        | load | service  | parameters |
        | 500    | 'devenv' | '1,2,3,x'    |

[When(@"I execute scenario '(.*)' in sequence (.*) times with parameters '(.*)'")]
    public void WhenIExecuteScenarioInSequenceTimesWithParameters(string p0, int p1, string p2)
    {
        var parameters = p2.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Cast<object>().Concat(new object[] { (string[])null }).ToArray();
        var feature = new LoadFeature();
        Enumerable.Range(0, p1).Select(x =>
        {
            var scenario = FindScenario<TelephonyLoadFeature>(p0);

            var parameters1 = new object[parameters.Length];
            Array.Copy(parameters, parameters1, parameters.Length);
            parameters1[parameters.Length - 2] = x.ToString();

            scenario.Invoke(feature, parameters1);
            return x;
        }).ToArray();
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one?

Comment: the 'ArgumentException' is a concurrency issue, the TypeRegistration.Resolve method must be being called twice in such quick succession that the object is not there when the check happens, then is being added twice causing the error, but I do not know how to work around it

Comment: I think if you decide to run the code in parallel yourself, then you are on your own. Specflow supports running in parallel in a number of ways, but 'rolling your own' like this is likely to get you into trouble that you'll have to get yourself out of.

Comment: @sam-holder I was not aware that you could run in parallel with specflow, could you point me in the direction of the documentation for this?

Comment: sure, you can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Parallel-Execution)

Comment: Looking again at your scenario though I don't think its going to support what you want. you are effectively trying to do load testing using specflow, and its not going to support that.

Comment: I thought that I might be running down a blind alley, but I was hopeful that there would be a way to make this work, it would be very nice to write some acceptance tests then create a simple load test by saying `when the acceptance test is run n times in parallel`